# In Ruby on Rails v5.2 and Puma v4, after restarting puma at the time of logrotate, unnecessary workers continue to remain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

We are uses Ruby on Rails v5.2 and Puma v4, rotating the Rails application log with logrotate, and restarting puma when it is rotated.

We uses puma restart with `pumactl phased-restart`, but we used to send SIGUSR1 signal to restart it.

Specifically, it is the following code.

```
test -s $pid && kill -USR1 "$(cat /path/to/app/tmp/pids/puma.pid)"
```

Refs: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/docs/restart.md

Although puma restarts without any problem for a while, after several restarts, unnecessary workers will be left as shown below. In the following, there are two worker 7s. Perhaps pid = 15241 seems to be an unnecessary worker.

```
$ ps aux | grep [p]uma
username     10096 22.8  3.0 3357088 1012940 ?     Sl   13:01   1:12 puma: cluster worker 0: 14749 [app]
username     10135 26.6  3.0 3562476 1016716 ?     Sl   13:01   1:22 puma: cluster worker 1: 14749 [app]
username     10196 17.9  3.4 3688000 1145328 ?     Sl   13:01   0:54 puma: cluster worker 2: 14749 [app]
username     10243 15.6  3.9 3753452 1287424 ?     Sl   13:01   0:46 puma: cluster worker 3: 14749 [app]
username     10325 16.8  3.6 3758280 1189004 ?     Sl   13:01   0:48 puma: cluster worker 4: 14749 [app]
username     10381 15.9  3.1 3423564 1034904 ?     Sl   13:01   0:45 puma: cluster worker 5: 14749 [app]
username     10420 16.6  3.2 3689844 1070112 ?     Sl   13:01   0:46 puma: cluster worker 6: 14749 [app]
username     10464 21.9  2.6 3155296 888148 ?      Sl   13:01   0:59 puma: cluster worker 7: 14749 [app]
username     14749  0.0  0.0 216884 20340 ?        Sl    7月19   0:56 puma 4.0.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:9292) [app]
username     15241 60.7  9.2 5273704 3049272 ?     Sl   11:02  75:20 puma: cluster worker 7: 14749 [app]
```

My question is, I would like to know how to restart puma without leaving unnecessary workers.

Or I would like to know if there is a way to find out what each worker is doing to find out why this is the case.

Or, please tell me if there is a way to put in logs etc and check the situation after the fact.

The main usage version is as follows.

- Ruby: 2.4.2
- Ruby on Rails: 5.2.2.1
- Puma: 4.0.0

As mentioned above, puma restarts are performed by `pumactl phased-restart`, but the situation was the same by sending SIGUSR1 signal.

Answer (score 0):

Puma's `phased-restart` is a rolling restart. Each worker is restarted one by one. The other thing, is that the command returns before the workers have been restarted.

I also use `phased-restart`, but I don't have `logrotated` restart Puma, but instead just have it `copytruncate` the log files. It allows the file descriptors to remain the same. Now, maybe there are unforeseen problems with my approach, but I haven't seen any issues yet.

Example logrotate config:

```
/path/to/rails/app/shared/log/*.log {
  compress
  copytruncate
  daily
  dateext
  dateformat .%Y%m%d
  dateyesterday
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
  rotate 36
  su app_user app_user
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Currently there is another reason to change from puma to unicorn. I will also refer to it when using puma.

I also asked a similar question on puma's GitHub repository, so I'd like to point you to the URL.

https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1891